# EVP_get_cipherbyname always returns null

Tags: c, macos, openssl, macos-sierra

I have a problem when calling `EVP_get_cipherbyname` on macOS:

```
const char *cipher_str = "aes-256-cbc";
const evp_cipher_st *cipher1 = EVP_aes_256_cbc();
const evp_cipher_st *cipher2 = EVP_get_cipherbyname(cipher_str);
```

In the code above, `cipher1` will always be set to a valid `evp_cipher_st *` object, and `cipher2` will always be null. I haven't found a single instance of `cipher_str` that produces a non-null `cipher2`.

Am I doing something wrong? Are there some other calls I should be making to get this to work?

Comment: Any reason to spam tags for two different languages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize the OpenSSL library first. If you just use libcrypto, 
call:

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
```

Refer to https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization for how to handle other situations or openssl versions.

Comment: Just in case somebody landed here like me: since OpenSSL 1.1.0 this is no longer needed.