# EVP_get_cipherbyname((const char *)[cipherName UTF8String]) becoming NULL

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to configure Touch ID from my app with "SSCrypto" using cipherName as aes128.

```
    if(cipherName)
    {
        cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname((const char *)[cipherName UTF8String]);
        if(!cipher)
        {
            NSLog(@"cannot get cipher with name %@", cipherName);
            return nil;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cipher = EVP_bf_cbc();
        if(!cipher)
        {
            NSLog(@"cannot get cipher with name %@", @"EVP_bf_cbc");
            return nil;
        }
    }
```

The above is the code I am executing. I am getting the cipher as NULL hence returning nil from this method.

Comment: 1. Are you sure there is a cipher with the exact name `aes128`? 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542613/evp-get-cipherbyname-always-returns-null

Comment: yes. I checked. It is there.